After using the timeout command in the container of the alpine image, a dead process will be left
I ran a container using the alpine image and used timeout to run a command in it. After the timeout command ran, there is a dead process left in alpine, and I cannot kill it using the kill command. My execution flow is as follows:
Run an alpine container
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.20.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.20"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues"

Use the timeout to execute a command
# timeout -k 10 5 /bin/sleep 20
Terminated

After that, a dead process with timeout is left in the container, and it cannot be killed with kill.
# ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sleep infinity
   18 root      0:00 sh
   33 root      0:00 [timeout]
   36 root      0:00 ps -ef
# kill -9 33
# ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 sleep infinity
   18 root      0:00 sh
   33 root      0:00 [timeout]
   37 root      0:00 ps -ef

timeout version
# timeout --help
BusyBox v1.36.1 (2024-05-21 13:38:37 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: timeout [-s SIG] [-k KILL_SECS] SECS PROG ARGS

Run PROG. Send SIG to it if it is not gone in SECS seconds.
Default SIG: TERM.If it still exists in KILL_SECS seconds, send KILL.


Most likely the parent of the timeout process terminated before the timeout process and therefore could not wait for it. When a process's parent dies before its child, the child is orphaned and adopted by the process with pid 1. This is normally the init process whose main task after starting up the system is to wait for the termination of such orphaned processes, but containers don't necessarily have such an init process (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162358/docker-init-zombies-why-does-it-matter for some discussion on this.)
Using the --init option to your docker run command should fix this.

Thank you for your answer, this solved my problem.
